# UICollectionView reordering: interactive movement or drag and drop?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uidragitem, uicontextmenuinteraction

As of iOS 9, UICollectionView supports interactive movement via [`beginInteractiveMovement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618019-begininteractivemovementforitema?language=objc) and its sibling methods. As of iOS 11, it also supports [drag and drop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/supporting_drag_and_drop_in_collection_views?language=objc), which [seems to support movement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdropcoordinator/2897310-dropitem?language=objc) as well. In iOS 13 beta 4, drag and drop gestures have been combined with `UIContextMenuInteraction` animations ([Twitter link](https://twitter.com/simonbs/status/1151583464032022534)) so you can transition from a context menu to a drag operation, but the same isn't true when reordering via the interactive movement APIs.

Is it better to implement interactive movement of items in a collection view using drag and drop going forward?

Answer (score 4):

It is better to migrate to `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDropDelegate`. I recently had a task where I had to combine context menu, reordering (after activation via context menu) and `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` with orthogonal sections.
I have to say, that if you use gesture recognizers and interactive movement, it will break scrolling in all orthogonal sections.